# How to filter a data set to numeric values only in apply() function in R?

Tags: r, apply

I tried to do:

```
apply(test,2,mean)
```

and I get this warning:

```
     CS.32   No..of.Takes         CS.130 No..of.Takes.1         CS.131 No..of.Takes.2         CS.133 No..of.Takes.3         CS.135 No..of.Takes.4 
        NA             NA             NA             NA             NA             NA             NA             NA             NA             NA 
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
7: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
8: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
9: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
10: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I want to filter the data set to compute for the means avoiding some non numeric values like NA, INC, DRP, etc.

Comment: Can you make your [question reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1315767)?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
colMeans(test[,sapply(test, is.numeric)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

I think it'll work.

Note that `colMeans(data.frame/matrix)` is the same (but better and a bit faster) as `apply(data.frame/matrix, 2, mean)`.

In my code, `test[,sapply(test, is.numeric)]` tests whether a specific column is numeric, if so, then its colmean is calculated via `colMeans`, otherwise it is skipped. Therefore `sapply(test, is.numeric)` is the "filter" you're looking for, it returns a boolean vector (`TRUE/FALSE`) indicating which column is numeric, you can use it to subset your data.frame/matrix.

See this example, consider `iris` dataset

```
> data(iris)
> apply(iris, 2, mean)  # NA's produced as in your case
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
          NA           NA           NA           NA           NA 
Mensajes de aviso perdidos
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
...

> apply(iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)], 2, mean)  # output is OK
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333 
> colMeans(iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)])        # same output
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```

Comment: It gave the means of some of the columns.

some of the columns have NA,DRP,INC. which was skipped during the computation. but columns with <NA> was ignored. the whole column where <NA> is present is ignored for computation.

how to deal with that?

Comment: `factor` and `character` should be skipped, as `mean` function only accepts `numeric` values, `NA` are also left over, because of `na.rm=TRUE` argument, otherwise the `mean` will return `NA`. Take a look at the documentation and make your problem reproducible. Btw what value for the mean do you expect from a column full of `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

add the parameter to ignore the NAs and make sure all your columns are numeric. You can check that using str(test)

```
 apply(test,2,mean,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: it still gave me the same warning above.

Answer (score 0):

alternative method.. step by step

- `b<-apply(test,2,as.numeric)`
- `good=complete.cases(b)`
- `c=b[good,]`
- `apply(c,2,mean)`